# What is the difference of summing left and right channel vs using just one of the two?

Tags: audio, output, input, stereo

Speaking about the sound levels, which is the correct way to connect a stereo output to a mono input?

Will the signal in case one be lower in amplitude, or is it not sessizable?

[image]

Comment: How would you connect two mono outputs to a mono input?

Comment: As in case one, with the minus of having half of the signal power if I understand well?

Comment: You won't hear voices on the right channel with one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way would be the usually accepted way.

In the first case, the mono output instantaneous signal amplitude (voltage) level is the average of the two mixed signals' individual instantaneous levels.

So mono sig_out = (left+right)/2

In the second case you will lose any signal information from the right channel that is not in the left channel. In a stereo signal the left and right channel signals are often not identical.

You need to check that 1k resistors won't  draw too much current from the signal sources for what they are able to provide based on maximum signal amplitude.

Comment: 1.So let s say left and right are perfectly the same: then (Left+right) /2 should be perfect the same thing as only right or left?

Comment: "You need to check that 1k resistors won't try and draw too much current from the signal sources for what they are able to provide based on maximum signal amplitude": what exactly should one search in datasheet amp max current output? And how do I calculate the value for resistor?

Comment: @CatalinaSirbu Yes, that's right, (3+3)/2 = 3. I would look at maximum output current as a guide and then size the resistors based on the signal voltage amplitude to draw a current from the source which is substantially less than the maximum obtainable. You could use Ohms Law for this R=Vpk/I where I is considerably less than the maximum current obtainable.  Alternatively just use some larger resistors, say 10k, which with a signal amplitude of 2 V will only draw 2/10k = 200uA, quite small compared to what a typical op amp is able to source or sink. Larger resistors mean more noise added.

Comment: Both answers (@Justme and @James) are what I'm looking for, I'll match this as selected answer because you answered first. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Both ways are equally correct electronically. Which one you want to choose depends on what you want to happen.

If you only take one of the channels, then you can't hear the other channel.

Now if that is OK or not, depends on what material you intend to play.

So this isn't really about sound levels. It does not really matter if the output sums amplitudes with half of left and half of right.

For material that plays the same audio on both channels, the output is approximately identical to one channel, with the exception of having extra resistances there.

For material that plays inverted audio on the other channel, the sum is just silence.

Comment: Very useful: "For material that plays inverted audio on the other channel, the sum is just silence."